# UBUNTU 22: Cannot get pairing code trying to pair Logitech ERGO K860

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

Ubuntu 20 on laptop: I have tried to pair via the GUI and also the CLI (bluetoothctl) and in neither case do I get the pairing code to enter. Soon after, it times out and fails.  How do I get it to give me to pairing code to type?  I can see it in the list in the GUI and the CLI gets its name so it is seeing the signal, but just no pairing code so I am stopped from using it.  I set discoverable and press the keys mentioned on the Logitech web site.

```
[ERGO K860]# pair d1:35:fd:17:f8:fe
Attempting to pair with D1:35:FD:17:F8:FE
[CHG] Device D1:35:FD:17:F8:FE Connected: no
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationCanceled
[CHG] Device D1:35:FD:17:F8:FE Connected: yes
```

Comment: title says "Ubuntu 22" (I guess Ubuntu 22.04, as 22.10 isn't out yet), Question says "Ubuntu 20" (20.04LTS?): which is it?